# Vacuum solutions of Einstein's field equations with $O(n)$ isometry group

Tags: reference-request, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

In *[Relativity and Singularities](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603190)*, Natário states that

> Any vacuum solution admitting $O(n)$ as an isometry group is locally isometric to $M=\mathbb{R}^2\times S^{n-1}$ (with the Schwarzchild metric).

Why is that so? It doesn't seem obvious to me, and, so far, all "proofs" on the web approach this problem from the *physical* point of view, so the connection to the above statement is blurred to me.

Comment: Search for "Birkhoff's theorem".

Comment: I did. I could not picture why it's the same statement as the one above.

Comment: Birkhoff's theorem states that any spherically symmetric solution (ie a solution admitting O(n) as an isometry group) of the vacuum field equations is unique and is indeed the Schwarzchild solution. This is exactly the statement in the op. Any "other" solution will be isometric to the Schwarzchild solution. The Schwarzchild solution is unique. The answer to the op is the proof of Birkhoff's theorem.